# How can I combine two columns into a one LIKE statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a lastname and a firstname.

I need to be able to search for smith or smith j.

I have this in my where clause:

```
lastname LIKE '%SMITH%' AND firstname LIKE '%J%'
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I combine the lastname and the first name for one LIKE for this?  The data does have a smith j in it.

Thank you for any help.

I am using Oracle 11g if that matters.

edit:  forgot to include quotes.  I did have that.  thanks.

edit:  It looks like I am doing it right so it must be something else.

Comment: The part where you mix lower case 'smith' and upper case 'J' is intentional?

Comment: maybe the field is Case-insensitivity? so '%j%' and '%J%' return other results?!

Comment: I think you need to show what data you have, what results you expect, and what results you are actually getting.  Because, actually, what you have should do what you've described...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
UPPER(lastname) LIKE '%SMITH%' AND UPPER(firstname) LIKE '%J%'
```

Or if you really need it in one statement:

```
UPPER(lastname||firstname) LIKE '%SMITH%J%'
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to observe case insensitivity that the question author is obviously missing.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I have misunderstood your question

```
lastname LIKE '%smith%'
```

by itself will return both?

Comment: Yes it will but I need to narrow it so that it uses the first name as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need apostrophes around the strings:

```
lastname LIKE '%smith%' AND firstname LIKE '%J%'
```

Answer (score 0):

how about instead of using like, use a regular expression that matches both?

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
(
  (lastname LIKE '%SMITH%') AND
  ( (firstname LIKE '%J%') OR (firstname IS NULL) OR (firstname ='') )
)
```